# How to deploy webapp written in python 3.3 to AWS/GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

My development environment is Django 1.5 / Python 3.3. Now when I am trying to deploy on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk, and found out they only support python 2.7. I believe the same thing with GAE. I would like to enjoy using the free tier of either platform, so anyone can offer some ideas?

Comment: Why don't you install Python3 on AWS? It's easy.

Comment: I am not familiar with how to build up from scratch, and thats why i choose beanstalk which is PaaS thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at a deployment platform that only supports Python 2.7, then you don't really have any option than to change to Python 2.7, or choose a different platform to deploy on.

If you use Python 2.7, there are plenty of from `__future__` imports that you can use to make your code closer to Python 3. See the [porting guide](http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/pyporting.html) for more info.